# Asking a question on the main site cause the question title, and body to be automatically filled

Tags: bug, questions

I was going to ask a new question on the main site; when I clicked on "Ask Question," the title and the body were automatically filled with text taken from a previous question I asked on the meta site.

[image: screenshot]

The question from which that text is taken is [What does "(deleted)" mean in the page listing my close-votes?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/what-does-deleted-mean-in-the-page-listing-my-closure-votes)

I don't think it was the browser that auto-completed the fields, since Google Chrome has never had this problem. (I asked many questions, and this is the first time it happened.)

The last questions I asked on the main site are the following:

- [Do Canadians and Americans really use "gotten" as past participle when speaking?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4878/do-canadians-and-americans-really-use-gotten-as-past-participle-when-speaking)
- [Can a sentence starting with "I think" be used to state a fact?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/can-a-sentence-starting-with-i-think-be-used-to-state-a-fact)

I didn't have any problem when I asked my previous question.

The last questions I asked on the meta site are the following:

- [The help text is missing a white space between two words](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/458/the-help-text-is-missing-a-white-space-between-two-words)
- [What does "(deleted)" mean in the page listing my close-votes?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/what-does-deleted-mean-in-the-page-listing-my-closure-votes)

Notice that the question that was copied in the question fields is not even the last I asked, and I am sure I asked both from the same browser running on the same computer.

Comment: The reply box saves a draft of [your post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/212576)(every 45 seconds).

Comment: That is correct, but it should not populate the questions fields with a question asked on a different site. If I start writing a post, and I change page after the draft is saved, and after answering to the dialog box, what I wrote is shown when I start edit the same time of post. Still, that should happen when I am in the same site, not when I am in a different site.

Comment: Interesting! Might stem from the fact that, other than MSO, main & meta technically are the same site. (We don't *see* them that way, but since rep is consistent between the two, there might be more coding overlap). Can't say for sure as I'm not a site dev, but this is interesting. Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: @WendiKidd I tried starting to write a post on the meta site of Drupal Answers, and then going to the main site after the draft was saved: Nothing happened. Notice that the post I was shown was not the last post I wrote on this very site, but the one before. If that would be the case, it should remember the last post I wrote. I would expect the draft to be forgotten when the post is posted, though.

Comment: Can you repro this or was it a one-off event? It might have been a glitch while re-deploying Redis. If you can repro can you provide steps?

Comment: @Sklivvz It happened just before I created this report; after that, it never happened again.

Comment: It is also true that I have not asked any question here, since this report.